# covr::package_coverage() is taking a long time

Tags: r-package, test-coverage, rstan

I am using the `covr::package_coverage` function to test the coverage of the package `EcoEnsemble':

https://github.com/CefasRepRes/EcoEnsemble

using the command

```
covr::package_coverage("EcoEnsemble",quiet=F)
```

The package seems to compile and gets stuck with the console saying:

```
C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o EcoEnsemble.dll tmp.def KF_back.o RcppExports.o stanExports_ensemble_model.o stanExports_ensemble_model_hierarchical.o stanExports_ensemble_prior.o stanExports_ensemble_prior_hierarchical.o -LC:/Users/MS23/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/RcppParallel/lib/x64 -ltbb -ltbbmalloc -LC:/Users/MS23/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/RcppParallel/lib/x64 -Wl,-rpath,C:/Users/MS23/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/RcppParallel/lib/x64 -ltbb -ltbbmalloc --coverage -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
```

I gave up after a day or so on a few occasions.

The package installs fine and passes the CRAN checks.

Can anyone help?

Thanks very much

Mike

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "1.2"

$year
[1] "2021"

$month
[1] "11"

$day
[1] "01"

$`svn rev`
[1] "81115"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"

$nickname
[1] "Bird Hippie"

> pkgbuild::rtools_path() 
[1] "C:\\rtools40/usr/bin"    "C:\\rtools40/ucrt64/bin"
```